# Categories appear in wrong order when assigned to a post

Tags: wordpress, categories

I have set up this hierarchy in categories as in the screenshot, for example

Men > Accessories > Ties

http://i48.tinypic.com/apjs3s.jpg

But when I assign a post with the categories Men > Accessories > Ties, it appears in the wrong order and it's happening for other posts and categories  too. For example here the order is Accessories > Men  > Ties. This is a problem because it appears like this in the breadcrumbs too. It's driving me insane please help!

http://i49.tinypic.com/2w4woqw.jpg

Answer (score 1):

As I know, categories in backend are displayed by default ordered alphabetically by slug  in ASCending mode.

I see in your images that you are using for the slug :subcat-cat. change it to cat-subcat... Or generally make the same hierarchy for the the categories in the way you are naming your slugs

Or add a function like above in your functions.php which will change the way categories  (and subcategories) are displayed  in backend.

for example, to show categories in dashboard admin by slug order in DESCending way :

```
add_filter( 'get_terms_args', 'wpse_53094_sort_get_terms_args', 10, 2 );
function wpse_53094_sort_get_terms_args( $args, $taxonomies ) 
{
    global $pagenow;
    if( !is_admin() || ('post.php' != $pagenow && 'post-new.php' != $pagenow) ) 
        return $args;

    $args['orderby'] = 'slug';
    $args['order'] = 'DESC';

    return $args;
}
```